# Difference between parameters taken by @RestController and @RequestMapping annotations?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

What does the parameter in `@RestController("/path/..")` do?
Does it not set the base path like `@RequestMapping("/path/..")`.
   What is the difference?

```
@RestController("base-path")
```

Comment: On a side note:
@ RequestMapping = Routing information that will be used by spring. Whereas
@ RestController = @ Controller + @ ResponseBody

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-annotations):

- `@RestController` -

> is known as a stereotype annotation. It provides hints for people
>   reading the code, and for Spring, that the class plays a specific
>   role. ... so Spring will consider it when handling incoming web
>   requests.

- `@RequestMapping` -

> annotation provides “routing” information. It is telling Spring that
>   any HTTP request with the path “/” should be mapped to the home
>   method. The @RestController annotation tells Spring to render the
>   resulting string directly back to the caller.

Answer (score 3):

In case of `@RestController` the parameter value depicts the component name or bean name, whereas in `@RequestMapping` the value parameter is used to specify the path. Both are used for different purpose.

If you want to specify request URI path on controller class name use `@RequestMapping` annotation with `@RestController`. Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/my-path")
@RestController
class MyController {
    ...
}
```

Comment: where can we use the Component name or bean name if we set it ?. Is it for use in getBean() method ?

Comment: Yes it can be used there or while auto wiring beans, it can be used in qualifiers. However, controllers should never be auto-wired.

Comment: If it is used as a component name, Then why does it work when `@RestController("/base")` is used and url contains `url.com/base` ?

Comment: it works as a component name only for the annotation which is meant to define components. `@RestController` is meant to define a component. `@RequestMapping` is meant to define the path.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping methods assume @ResponseBody semantics by default .
@RequestMapping is relatively traditional.

@RestController which combined the behavior of @Controller and @ResponseBody together. @RestController is relatively new.

Answer (score 0):

**RestController:**
A convenience annotation that is itself annotated with @Controller and @ResponseBody.
Types that carry this annotation are treated as controllers where @RequestMapping methods assume @ResponseBody semantics by default.

**RequestMapping:**
Annotation for mapping web requests onto methods in request-handling classes with flexible method signatures.
Both Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux support this annotation through a RequestMappingHandlerMapping and RequestMappingHandlerAdapter in their respective modules and package structure. For the exact list of supported handler method arguments and return types in each.

conclusion:
RestController does not handle the path