# Request gets another method in controller(SpringBoot)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have 2 method in controller:

```
@RestController("/api/v1/users")
public class UserController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getUserByEmailAndPassword(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        logger.info("Request to get user with email and password: " + email + password);
        User user = userService.checkUserByEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        return user != null ? Collections.singletonList(user) : Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<UserDto> getUserByEmail(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
        logger.info("Request to get user with email: " + email);
        UserDto userDto = userService.checkUserEmail(email);
        return userDto != null ? Collections.singletonList(userDto) : Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

CORS config:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

When I send request to: http://localhost:9092/api/v1/users/login?email=art&password=1037006322

I calling this method *getUserByEmail*

How it is possible?
How to fix this problem?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? Currently it works as expected due to `@RequestMapping` first being applied from class level and then from method level.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Request  http://localhost:9092/api/v1/users/login?email=art&password=1037006322 should call getUserByEmailAndPassword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map this way.it will work as per your requirement.Map your url pattern with @RequestMapping instead of @RestController.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getUserByEmailAndPassword(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        logger.info("Request to get user with email and password: " + email + password);
        User user = userService.checkUserByEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        return user != null ? Collections.singletonList(user) : Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<UserDto> getUserByEmail(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
        logger.info("Request to get user with email: " + email);
        UserDto userDto = userService.checkUserEmail(email);
        return userDto != null ? Collections.singletonList(userDto) : Collections.emptyList();
    }

 }
```

Comment: It would be great if you can explain what is the difference between mapping uri to `@RestController` and `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: Just check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891083/difference-between-parameters-taken-by-restcontroller-and-requestmapping-annot